# Update a table column with shuffled numbers within a range

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to update a table column -`Code`- with shuffled numbers within its range, with no duplicates and without missing a number from the range. 
for example the range is 1-9 and the following is the table:

```
Id|Name|Code

1 | AC | 2  
2 | AB | 1  
3 | CB | 5  
4 | DE | 9  
5 | FE | 3  
6 | AE | 4  
7 | FD | 6  
8 | BD | 7  
9 | DC | 8
```

I want result like in the above example. I am using `SQL Server 2008`.

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 
(SELECT TOP 100 percent COUNT(*) FROM 
TABLENAME ORDER BY NEWID() )
AS INT)+2

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( ID INT, Code INT )

INSERT  INTO @t
        ( ID )
VALUES  ( 1 ),
        ( 2 ),
        ( 3 ),
        ( 4 ),
        ( 5 ),
        ( 6 ),
        ( 7 ),
        ( 8 ),
        ( 9 );
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY NEWID() ) AS rn
               FROM     @t
             )
    UPDATE  cte
    SET     code = rn


SELECT  *
FROM    @t
```

Output:

```
ID  Code
1   2
2   7
3   4
4   1
5   6
6   8
7   5
8   9
9   3
```

If you want to manually set the range then you can set starting number of range and do something like:

```
DECLARE @start INT = 101

DECLARE @t TABLE ( ID INT, Code INT )

INSERT  INTO @t
        ( ID )
VALUES  ( 1 ),
        ( 2 ),
        ( 3 ),
        ( 4 ),
        ( 5 ),
        ( 6 ),
        ( 7 ),
        ( 8 ),
        ( 9 );

WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY NEWID() ) AS rn
               FROM     @t
             )
    UPDATE  cte
    SET     code = rn + @start - 1


SELECT  *
FROM    @t
```

Output:

```
ID  Code
1   104
2   108
3   107
4   105
5   102
6   103
7   106
8   101
9   109
```

Comment: I m doing it in this way also

Comment: CREATE TABLE #TEMP(TOTREG INT NULL)
DECLARE '@cnt INT = 1;
WHILE '@cnt <= 9
 BEGIN
  INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ('@cnt)
  SET @cnt = '@cnt + 1;
 END;
 
UPDATE TAB_EXAM_FORMS
SET
RNO_CODE= How to update?
WHERE 
SESSION_ID='46'

Comment: what is the sessionid?

Comment: -sessionid- is also a column of that table 
i want to update only those rows where sessionid is 46

Comment: Edit your question with relevant table structure and data. It is not clear for me.

Answer (score 0):

- `NEWID()` will give us a type of random id that you can use it for shuffling
- As Giorgu Nakeuri answer you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` for a range of continuous and always start from `1`

So I suggest you to use a query like this for shuffling a non-continues Range with different start point of `1`:

```
;With t as (    
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) As rndrn
    FROM (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) As rn 
        FROM yourTable ) t1)
SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT ti.Id FROM t ti WHERE ti.rn = t.rndrn) As Code
FROM t
ORDER BY Id
```

Sample Result is:

```
ID  Name Code
2   AB   2
3   CB   8
4   DE   7
5   FE   5
6   AE   6
7   FD   9
8   BD   3
9   DC   11
11  AC   4
```